# Loop through each Folder and delete some of them

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the script below in multiple paths using an array. My goal is to delete folders keeping the last 7 versions, but it is not working as expected. The action is only taking into account the first path `D:\Test1`.

I believe that I should add something like `($folders in $folders)` after `ForEach-Object` but I don know how.

Any idea what I missing here?

```
$path = @("D:\Test1","D:\Test2","D:\Test3")
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | 
           Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
           Group-Object { $_.Name.Split('_')[0] } |
           ForEach-Object $Folders {
             $_.Group |
             sort CreationTime -Descending |
             Select -Skip 7 |
             foreach { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from @Robert Israelsson !

" If you change your group-object to not group by name but instead fullname you will get the desired result."

From:

```
$folders= Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[0] }
```

To:

```
$folders= Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |Group-Object {$_.FullName.Split('_')[0] }
```

And this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This should do your job.

```
$path= @("D:\Test1","D:\Test2","D:\Test3")
$folders= Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |Group-Object {$_.FullName.Split('_')[0] }
ForEach($folder in $folders)
{
$folder.Group | sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 7|% { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -whatIf}
}
```

I tested in my local and it is working fine. Although I didn't get any error in your code except few formatting issue which I have taken into variable and sorted it out cause I got tangled in too many pipeline objects.

If you are using *foreach* after a pipeline , that means it will take the pipeline objects one by one only. But if you are separately using it , then you have to assign each iteration into a variable.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, the script looks better, but it is still not working as expected, I mean the action is just taking into account the first path "D:\Test1" and now is deleting everything in the others...

Just in case, I'm using the script below to create test folders in two different paths:

1..10 | Foreach-Object {New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST_1\Folder_"$_"}
1..10 | Foreach-Object {New-Item -ItemType Directory C:\Users\ad_karendex\Documents\TEST_1\Test_"$_"}

Comment: Let me check that. @Tana_CR

Comment: The solution is not working in PowerShell version 2 just in v3...the big issue is that our Production server is using PS v2. Any idea?

Comment: whats the error you are facing? Can you see the pipeline objects that it is able to retrieve the data or not ?